# Recover a vector bundle by (some) restrictions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

**Problem:** Consider a smooth, projective variety $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, consider a vector bundle $E\xrightarrow{\pi}X$ os rank $r$. Suppose that $\mathbb{P}^k$ is a subvariety of $X$, and we know that for example $E|_{\mathbb{P}^k}=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^k}(a)^{\oplus s}$ for some $a,s$ (I'm trying to be as vague as possible).

**Question:** Is there any chance to describe $E$ (or some hypothesis to put in order to have a result)? How can we parametrize the possible bundles on $X$ whose restrictions to a certain projective space contained in $X$ have a certain beahviour? (can we even do better? replacing $\mathbb{P}^k$ with a smooth projective subvariety $Y$?)

I apologize in advance forr the vagueness of the question: I'm often computing bundles but I always know some restrictions of them, thus I was wondering if there is some theory about it (maybe it's a well known area of research, or there's a preicse reference I don't know of: I tried to look online unsuccessfully). Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are examples of rank $2$ vector bundles on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ for which the splitting of the bundle on lines (provided by Grothendieks splitting theorem) changes depending on the line.

This phenomena is explored in the book "Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces" by Okonek, Spindler, and Schneider. The splitting will be constant on a generic line, but it may be different on a special set of lines called "Jump Lines". A large class of rank $2$ bundles on $\mathbb{CP}^2$  with jump lines where produced by Scharzenbergger, the construction is explained in the book.

Comment: Jumping lines are also discussed in Eisenbud-Harris's *3264 and All That*. In one of the middle chapters they compute the degree (as a curve in $\mathbb P^{2\vee}$) of the locus of jumping lines for a bundle on $\mathbb P^2$.

Comment: Thanks both for the references, I'll check it out!